# i can't access uid from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

1. I can't access uid from firebase. I tried so many times. can anyone help me with this issue?

```
    class Massages extends StatelessWidget {
        
          @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return FutureBuilder(
                future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),
                builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
                  if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('chat')
                          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> chatSnapshot) {
                        if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        return ListView.builder(
                          reverse: true,
                          itemCount: chatSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
                            chatSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['text'],
                            chatSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['userId'] ==
                                futureSnapshot.data?.uid,
                            key: ValueKey(chatSnapshot.data!.documentID),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                });   } }
```

Comment: Recommendation: add to the question what happens instead of what you want. If you put the expected behaviour beside the actual behaviour often the bug becomes obvious.

Comment: chatSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['userId'] ==
                                futureSnapshot.data?.uid,        this uid i can't accees here show error

Comment: error mesage The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'uid', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'uid'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `futureSnapshot.data` returns an `Object` rather than a [`User`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html). You could try casting it to the correct type with:

```
((User)futureSnapshot.data)?.uid,
```

Comment: i think this two line code  create problem . future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser), and chatSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data?.uid,